# Sorting on two dimensions in a one dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, node.js, sorting

Say I have a one-dimensional list like so

```
A8, C3, C7, F9, A3, V3, J2
```

If I want to sort this list alphabetically by the first character and numerically by the second character, how can I do this?

I assume that I would have to prioritize a certain sort, and deprioritize secondary sorts, for example:

```
A1, B2, C1
```

A1 will definitely be first, but then the question is, should it be:

`{A1, C1, B2}`, or `{A1, B2, C1}` ?

My final question is, if I want to prioritize the numeric sorting, I assume I would do that as the second sort, not the first sort for standard sorting algorithms in most languages?

I am mostly concerned with sorting with regard to an implementation like so in C++

```
struct CustomSort{

    bool operator()(tuple<int,regex> const &lhs, tuple<int,regex> const &rhs){
        return std::get<0>(lhs) > std::get<0>(rhs);
    }
};
```

Comment: What is your data structure? A container of strings?

Comment: yeah for the purposes of the question assume it's an array of strings, with each string has a first character of a letter of the alphabet and the second character a number.

Comment: the C++ code references a tuple, but please assume that the first elements of the tuple represent the array in question.

Comment: does the question make sense to you? I hope it's clear. I just want to do this right.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array (`arr`) is a container of `std::string`, and that you want to prioritize the numerical sorting (i.e. `C1 < A3`), you can do it using a single call to [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) (I am using a c++11 lambda here but you could use a custom `Comparator` if you need):

```
std::sort(begin(arr), end(arr), [](std::string const& lhs, std::string const& rhs) {
    return std::tie(lhs[1], lhs[0]) < std::tie(rhs[1], rhs[0]);
});
```

I am not converting the second `char` to an `int` since the standard guarantees `'0' < '1' < ... < '9'`, but this assumes that you have only numbers between `0` and `9`.

If you want to prioritize the sorting on the first character, you simply have to do a standard `std::sort`:

```
std::sort(begin(arr), end(arr));
```

Comment: You can even do `return std::tie(lhs[1], lhs[0]) < std::tie(rhs[1], rhs[0]);` (that avoids to make a invalid comparer).